# iOS: Is this a good way to open your app's review section in the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am using the following string `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id284882215?action=write-review` to open the review section of my App. (For this example, I am using facebook app id). 
This method works very well (tested it on iOS 12 for both iPhone and iPad).

However, I have seen a lot of different ways to open the review section of your app in the app store. I just want to make sure this is a correct way and it has no pitfalls. One of my biggest concerns is that this won't work for iOS 11. I currently don't have an iOS 11 device, but according to some StackOverflow posts, this should work.

Comment: The best way to prompt for reviews is using the SKStoreReviewController API (iOS 10.3+) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/. See Apple's developer guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/.

Comment: To add to what @particleman said, SKStoreReviewController is the only approach you should use. If you check the App Store Review guidelines, 1.17 says “we disallow custom review prompts”. If you don’t use SKStoreReviewController, and Apple see it, you’re running the risk of your app being rejected or pulled from the store.